# Database Design for Limited Handful of Questionnaires

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

Suppose I have a user who can take zero or more questionnaires. A questionnaire has zero or more questions, and the user can have one response to each question.

A questionnaire is defined by the application, and where or how is where I am stuck. I can imagine tables such as these:

```
User (has many UserQuizzes)
UserQuiz (belongs to a QuizTemplate, has many UserQuizQuestionResponses)
UserQuizQuestionResponse (which belongs to a QuizTemplateQuestion)

QuizTemplate (has many QuizTemplateQuestions)
QuizTemplateQuestion (belongs to QuizTemplate)
```

However, the `QuizTemplate` and `QuizTemplateQuestion` data would be infrequently changed. Also, suppose that there are not that many - maybe 5 `QuizTemplates` with 20 `QuizTemplateQuestions` each. I think they are more like configuration and fixtures for the application rather than user-specified data. Would it be sensible to build the questions more like "configuration" at the application layer (big hashes? YML?)? Are physical tables the necessarily more robust option?

Comment: This is a perfect situation to use has_many :through.

Comment: You only really need to setup one side of the has_many :through, where a User has_many :quiz_templates and a User has_many :user_quizzes, :through quiz_templates. UserQuizzes will store user_id and quiz_template_id. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many for more details